# A matrix equation to solve

Tags: matrices

Let $C$, $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ and $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ be positive real numbers. How solve this equation in general to end up with a general formula for each $x_k$?
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
p_1    & p_2    & p_3    & \cdots & p_{n-1} & p_n    \\
q_1    & -q_2   & 0      & \cdots & 0       & 0      \\
0      & q_2    & -q_3   & \cdots & 0       & 0      \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  & \vdots \\
0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & q_{n-1} & -q_n
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n
\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{c}
C \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the top row to the bottom, the matrix is nearly in row echelon form.